# Windows Phone App only for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, marketplace

Is it possible to make a Windows Phone App target **only** the Windows Phone 7 platform?

I already have the Windows Phone 8 version of the app out, and changed a few things to release for Windows Phone 7 (like resolutions and limitations etc) but when I'm adding it to the marketplace it always has "Supported OS: Windows Phone 7 & 8" and doesn't allow me to change it.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect Microsoft intend for you to detect device/OS capabilities and implement functionality where possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is possible, if you upload a 7.5 app it can run on both WP7 og WP8 devices. If you also have an WP8 version of your app, the user with WP8 devices only get the 8 app and not the 7.5 app. Also if the user on WP8 device first download a WP7.5 version of your app, and you later uploads a WP8 version, the WP8 devices will be updated with the WP8 version when ready on the store!

Comment: I see, but won't there be two instances of my app in the marketplace for WP8 then?

Comment: No, only the WP8 app will be installed, and only the WP8 app will be shown in Windows Store for WP8 devices. You can have different image and text for WP7.5 version and the WP8 version